# Can we apply hoverintent plugin twice to same element? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hoverintent

I am using hoverintent plugin on "a" tag that contains images inside it.

I want to use it twice because there are two things to be done when one hovers on "a" tag but with different intervals.

```
//HoverIntent1
$("a.classname").hoverIntent({   
 sensitivity: 4, 
 interval: 300, 
 over: functionName,   
 timeout: 300,
 out: functionName
})

//HoverIntent2
$("a.classname").hoverIntent({   
  sensitivity: 3, 
  interval: 10, 
  over: functionName, 
  timeout: 10,
  out: functionName
})
```

When I run this it only executes functions inside one hoverintent and not both, I tried to find on net but could not find a satisfactory answer for the same.

Comment: Not sure, but you can perhaps give another class name to the same 'a' tag and bind it to two different classes. If you don't find the exact solution that is.

Comment: yes tried that in the morning but did not work..

Comment: How about wrapping the 'a' tag in another element, like Div or Span and then binding to that?

Comment: yes that would work.. but was unable to understand why didnt it work on same element with two different classes.
anyways thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the 'a' tag in another element, like Div or Span and then bind to that.